# PHP unique 10 digit numbers str_shuffle

Tags: php, numbers, unique, digit

Assuming i have a 1 million 10 digit unique numeric numbers. If i do a str_shuffle for each of the 1 million numbers , will the uniqueness still be maintained???? Please suggest

---

Thanks guys for some clarity,but the problem still remains.Actually, the million nos that i am talking of are all uniques numbers(infact they are mobile numbers 10 digits).i want to give these million nos to some client but i do not want them to have actual nos.Therefore,i need to randomise each number and generate an equivalent 10 digit unique number which i can give to the client and keep the mapping in my DB.I am looking for sum algo which does not do much of processing for the script otherwise i am sure the script will break down if i follow the traditional path of arrays and stuff

Answer (score 6):

No.

`str_shuffle('1234567890')` might give you "3124567890".

`str_shuffle('9876543210')` might also give you "3124567890", etc etc.

Answer (score 3):

It's pretty obvious that the answer is no.

ANY modifications to single numbers which do not care about ALL other numbers may result in duplicates.

Random shuffling is such a modification as it just mixes up the digits in a single number so chances are good to get a duplicate (Any math guys out there who want to calculate the probability? Looking forward to some comments about that.)

Answer (score 1):

str_shuffle is not unique by default as far as I know. It just randomly shuffles the string. Theoretically it would thus be possible that all 1 million numbers will be the same.

Comment: That is not the problem here.

Comment: You mean it is not clear enough..? It answers the question I think, namely 'No'.

Answer (score 1):

Counter example:

```
<?php

$unique_numbers = array('101', '110');

foreach($unique_numbers as $number){
    echo str_shuffle($number) . PHP_EOL;
}
```

I got:

```
011
011
```

Answer (score 1):

The statement of problem suggests you may actually wish to shuffle the array elements, and not the contents of those elements. Perhaps you'd be able to maintain uniqueness but have a randomly distributed set by swapping elements of the array for a while - ie swap random element A with random element B for N iterations.

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is a permutation script, which I happen to have for you.

```
function permuteString($str) 
{ 
    $aStr = str_split($str); 
    $iSize = count($aStr); 
    $aResult = array(); 

    for ($i = 0; $i < $iSize; ++$i) 
    { 
        $sFirst = array_shift($aStr); 
        $aInner = $aStr; 
        $iInner = count($aInner); 
        for ($j = 0; $j < $iInner; ++$j) 
        { 
            $aResult[] = $sFirst . implode('', $aInner); 
            $sTmp = array_shift($aInner); 
            $aInner[] = $sTmp; 
        } 
        $aStr[] = $sFirst; 
    } 
    return $aResult; 
} 

$userinput="1234567890"; 
print_r(permuteString($userinput));
```

This will print every possible permutation of the given userinput variable.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you define 'uniqueness' as.

When you say the 1 million set of 10-digit numbers, if you want to use `str_shuffle` on all of them, and then when you say unique, you mean at least 1 of the 1 million 10-digit phone numbers didn't exist before shuffling or what? If so, look here:

10! is 3628800. That's bigger than 1 million by a lot. So there's even a 2 in 3 chance that all the numbers will be random.

This means that if you use `str_shuffle` on all of the numbers, you will most likely (over 66% chance) get a 'unique' set, no matter what you define unique as.

Comment: I wouldn't call over 66% chance most likely, or at least I wouldn't trust a 66% chance if it is important that they are unique :-p